# Wet poster wrinkle effect with cloth simulation

Tags: cloth-simulation

I'm trying to create a specific effect with the cloth simulation. I want to create a glued poster, which can find in public spaces, see the reference image below:
[image: Wet poster effect]

The closest I can get is using a Turbulence force, but the wrinkles remain very big and fluffy.
[image]

Comment: It has to be with Cloth Simulation? What I mean is that if you don't need to be a simulation you could follow other pipeline.

Comment: Agreed. Unless you absolutely need to use cloth for other reasons, you could simply subdivide a plane in high resolution and sculpt what you need.